# haskell constraint families

Tags: haskell, types

I'm starting to get my feet wet with the new class constraint extensions in GHC 7.4.2, but I am having some problems getting a small example to work.  The code is as follows:

```
{-# LANGUAGE UndecidableInstances,
         MultiParamTypeClasses,
         KindSignatures,
         TypeFamilies,
         Rank2Types,
         ConstraintKinds,
         FlexibleInstances,
         OverlappingInstances #-}

module Test where

  import GHC.Exts  -- to get Constraint type constructor

  class NextClass f where
    type Ctxt f a :: Constraint
    next :: (Ctxt f a) => a -> a

  instance NextClass Int where
    type Ctxt Int a = Num a
    next b = b + 1

  n :: (NextClass a) => a -> a
  n v = next v
```

What I want to do is define a `NextClass` type class, which will allow me to (given a value x) get the next value of x for all types that are instances of the `NextClass`.  To use the `+` operator, I need the `Num a` class constraint for `Int`.

However, GHC gives me the following error:

```
Could not deduce (Ctxt f0 a) arising from a use of `next'
from the context (NextClass a)
   bound by the type signature for n :: NextClass a => a -> a
In the expression: next v
In an equation for `n': n v = next v
```

I suspect that GHC is telling me it does not have enough information to determine which constraint family instance to use.

Could someone explain what I am doing wrong here.  Is this a correct use of constraint families?

TIA

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There's a few odd things going on in your definition. First of all, the class variable `f` is never mentioned in the type of the (only) class method `next`. How is the compiler supposed to choose which instance of the type class to use? I'm going to assume you meant this:

```
{-# LANGUAGE ConstraintKinds, TypeFamilies #-}
module Test where

import GHC.Exts  -- to get Constraint type constructor

class NextClass f where
    type Ctxt f :: Constraint
    next :: Ctxt f => f -> f

instance NextClass Int where
    type Ctxt Int = Num Int
    next b = b + 1

n :: (NextClass a) => a -> a
n v = next v
```

The next oddity is that `Int` already has a `Num` instance, so this isn't much of a constraint. But let's leave that aside for now (since it doesn't affect the error we get) and just look at the new error:

```
test.hs:15:7:
    Could not deduce (Ctxt a) arising from a use of `next'
    from the context (NextClass a)
      bound by the type signature for n :: NextClass a => a -> a
      at test.hs:15:1-12
    In the expression: next v
    In an equation for `n': n v = next v
```

Actually, this error looks quite sensible: the whole point of the constraint is that having an instance for `NextClass a` isn't enough; we must also have an instance of `Ctxt a`. So we can fix up the type signature:

```
n :: (NextClass a, Ctxt a) => a -> a
n v = next v
```

...and then it compiles. The final oddity is that this is a particularly degenerate use of constraint kinds, since this simpler code is essentially equivalent:

```
class NextClass f where
    next :: f -> f

instance Num Int => NextClass Int where
    next b = b + 1
```

...and the translation from the previous thing to the new thing is quite mechanical: instead of declaring `instance NextClass {- foo -} where type Ctxt {- foo -} = {- bar -}`, you just write `instance {- bar -} => NextClass {- foo -}` instead.

Comment: Thanks Daniel,  I changed my code to use the `instance Num Int => NextClass Int where ...`.  Is this the idiomatic way to write this type of code in Haskell?

Comment: @RouanvanDalen Well, the idiomatic way is either `instance NextClass Int where ...` with no trivial constraints or `newtype SuccNext a = SuccNext a; instance Num a => NextClass (SuccNext a) where ...` with a polymorphic type (and a newtype to prevent spurious overlapping).